# Is the magnetism of a natural magnet caused by the same spin of the electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Is the magnetism of a natural magnet caused by the same spin of the electrons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Natural magnets consist of magnetite, essentially Fe$_3$O$_4$ with some other impurities. The iron ions have magnetic moments because of the electron spins in the 3d orbitals: Fe$^{3+}$ has a moment of five Bohr magnetons, Fe$^{2+}$ has a magnetic moment of about 4 Bohr magnetons. The magnetic arrangement is ferrimagnetic, the two Fe$^{3+}$ moments are opposite to each other, this leaves a moment of about 4 Bohr magnetons per formula unit.

Magnetite is a common mineral, it is an important iron ore. Yet natural magnets are rare. They were always found near the surface, never in mines. The explanation for this is that they got magnetized by the strong fields close to lightning strikes.

See also page 32 in a [chapter by Coey](https://application.wiley-vch.de/books/sample/3527331794_c01.pdf)